# How does the AMP cache work exactly?

Tags: amp-html

Let's assume I have an html page `www.acme.com/home.html` that **talks about cats**.

At some point I decide to provide an AMP version of such page. I will link (as per documentation) such alternative version from the original page. Like so:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://acme.com/amp-home.html">
```

Now what happens from now on is, I believe, the following:

1. The user will never directly end up to `amp-home.html`. Why should he/she? I have not linked that page anywhere so unless he reads the HTML source code he will never find out about `amp-home.html`.
2. A google bot will one day come to my `home.html` and discover about the page AMP version.
3. Google will cache `amp-home.html`.

That is it as far as me and google is concerned. Or is it?

Now, a user will go to Google and type "cats". My website talks about cats and so Google decides to return a link to my home page as well as part of the results set.

Now, assuming google decides it's best to return an AMP page, my question is the following:

Will Google return a link to `www.acme.com/amp-home.html` or to the version it cached? Something like: `www.google.com/amp-cache-whatever/page/www.acme.com/home.html`

In other words, is the link to my physical AMP page (the one hosted in my server) ever provided by Google? Or does G always return its cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Google does cache valid AMP pages, you can choose to [link directly to them in cache](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview).

It looks like it will always try and serve from it's cache. If you are worried about tracking traffic, if you use Google Analytics you can set it up to track AMP pages.

Answer (score 1):

## G always returns its cache

According to the [Google AMP Cache Home](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/):

> Google products, including Google Search, serve valid AMP documents and their resources from the cache to provide a fast user experience across the mobile web.